# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher.png')

Tags: android, android-manifest

[image]I changed launcher icons in my application. The images I added are of PNG format. But when i clean and build my project, it is giving below error.

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher.png').

Below is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: are you sure you have mipmap folders under your res directory? it seems that message is obvious and there is no resource there

Comment: Yes I have. I just replaced the default launcher icons :S

Comment: in this case we need more info: -screenshot of your res folder, - the icon itself (it may be corrupted, or wrong format) - when do you get an error, on compiling step, or on app start?

Comment: it seems that your manifest is generated and it probably trying to find launcher icon in different project

Comment: What tool/lib do you use that could generate manifest file?

Comment: I'm using Android studio.

Comment: what is the version of gradle, build tools and android studio?

Comment: gradle-2.2.1, Android Studio 1.1.0

Answer (score 31, accepted):

remove the file's extensions  from `android:icon`

Change from

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher.png"
```

to

```
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

and please make sure that you have `ic_launcher.png` in the `mipmap` folder

Edit:

From the screenshot you posted it looks like you are editing the wrong manifest file. Please be sure of editing the one under `src/main/manifests`

Comment: that was after I build the project. I will modify the question.

Comment: I have added images as name ic_launcher.png in mipmap folders. After that I'm getting this error when I clean my project.

Comment: did you remove the file's extensions ?

Comment: Yeah. Actually at the very first place I have not added the extension. It is automatically being added when you build your project.

Comment: that sounds more like a bug to me.

Comment: did you add the various  `mipmap-mdpi`,  `mipmap-hdpi` folders under res?

Comment: Yes. mipmap-mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi and xxhdpi

Comment: launcher takes the icon with higher resolution than you have on your device, so you should add all resolution folders there

Comment: and in each of them you added your `ic_launcher.png` file?

Comment: But earlier when there were default icons ,there were 4 folders only. I dont understand why while compiling it does not find the images.

Comment: Yes I just changed the images leaving everything else as it was including the name.

Comment: check the filename again? Maybe exporting the new files some strange/invisible chars was added.. or a space

Comment: I added screenshot. Please check

Comment: you are editing the wring AndroidManifest.xml. The screenshot says that you are editing the one under build

Comment: actually @Blackbelt is right you are editing wrong manifest file, open the one under src/main folder :)

Comment: Got it. I clicked on the error and it opened the manifest which was building. Solved the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Check if these settings are ***point to the right directory***

[image]

This panel is-->project structure-->facets.

Hope this is work for you !

Answer (score 2):

I recently came to an solution just open the "android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest" in android studio or whatever editor you have and edit "ic_launcher" with your icon name then error will be gone and app gets your custom icon

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to close the `AnroidManifest.xml` tab.
2. Search and open your basic manifest ...
3. `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

*(Had the same issue because the error appears on **AUTOMATICALLY** generated manifest, new one)*

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar issue. When creating a new `react-native-app`, there are two sets of icons - `ic_launcher.png` & `ic_launcher_round.png` in the `android/src/main/res/mipmap-` directories.

If you replaced the default icon with your own icon set, make sure to also provide a round icon of your app logo with the name `ic_launcher_round.png` in all of these folders.

Hopefully the error should resolve.

Answer (score 0):

keep your icons to mipmap-hdpi or mipmap-mdpi folders etc.
Do not keep your app icon to plane "mipmap" folder

Answer (score 0):

if you've manipulated attributes on the MainActvity class make sure the icon value doesn't contain an extension

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error.

I copied the images from this directory:
`...\app\src\debug\res\mipmap-mdpi`

I pasted it here:
`...\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi`

problem solved

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that the ic_launcher was generated in the Debug folder. So that is why when I was trying to Build signed apk, there was the Manifest error - ic_launcher not found [image]